# _extend.less doesn't seem to work

Tags: magento2.3.0, less-compilation

I'm trying to add a new less file into an already existing theme, which will turn the price classes descended from the special-price class red, highlighting a 'discount' and making it more obvious

```css
.special-price .price {
    color: red !important;
}
```

This is in a file called _special_price.less, which is imported into the _extend.less file.

```css
@import '_special_price.less';
```

It is my understanding that 
_extend is compiled last, which means any existing CSS is overwritten, but this doesn't seem to be happening, as the expected change is absent.

Yes, I realize that !important shouldn't be needed, but it didn't even work anyway.

I have flushed and cleaned the cache, compiled, deployed, anything I can think of. Can anyone help?

Edit:

After more experiments, I have concluded that the whole CSS file in the custom theme is not even being compiled. changes to existing (and working) .less files produce no change, as when the webpage is inspected, the previous CSS is still there.

Comment: In which location are you create '_special_price.less' ?

Comment: in the web/css/source folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can import less in following way.

`_extend.less` is availble in following path `app/design/frontend/<vendor name>/<theme name>/web/css/source/_extend.less`

You have to write in `_extend.less` file

```
@import 'special_price.less';
```

After adding changes run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I have tried this way, and after inspecting the resulting web-page, I found no change.

Comment: You can review Sample less theme on github. https://github.com/vrajeshkpatel/V4U-Samplelesstheme

Comment: If mode is set to developer `bin/magento c:c` is enough for theme changes.